# Error registering Kibana Privileges with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am running my elasticsearch and then running kibana by going to path/bin and executing kibana.bat

version : kibana7.4.0, elasticsearch6.4.3

From https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/using-kibana-with-security.html It mentions xpack security which I don't even see on my kibana.yml file.

I've uncommented

```
server.port:5601
server.host:"localhost"
elasticsearch.hosts:["http://localhost:9200"]
```

When I run kibana.bat It outputs multiple of these same error message:

```
[0
4:53:06.415] [error][security] Error registering Kibana 
Privileges with Elasticsearch for kibana-.kibana: 
[index_not_found_exception] no such index, with { 
resource.type="index_expression" & resource.id="_security" & 
index_uuid="_na_" & index="_security" }
```

by the way I am using windows 10. Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION :** simply downgrading kibana to 6.4.3. works.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to increase your Elasticsearch version. See this post closed by the Elastic team : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-7-1-1-error-registering-kibana-privileges-with-elasticsearch/183370